# Swift: calculate percentage for each element in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I set an array for storing income values per month in USD:

```
let incomePerMonthArray = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Also I set constant, which represents tax in %:

```
let taxRate = 10.0
```

I need to calculate tax in USD for each element in `incomePerMonthArray` and store it in a new array.

What is the best way to do that?

---

I successfully used following function for single values:

```
//Calucate percentage based on given values
public func calculatePercentage(value:Double, percentageVal:Double) -> Double {
    let val = value * percentageVal
    return val / 100.0
}
let taxInUSD = calculatePercentage(value: Double(incomePerMonth), percentageVal: taxRate)
```

But it doesn't work with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map statement.

```
let taxesPerMonth: [Double] = incomePerMonthArray.map { calculatePercentage(value: $0, percentageVal: taxRate) }
```

That will call your `calculatePercentage(value: percentageValue:)` function on every element in yoru income array, and the result will be a new array containing the taxes for each income.

Note that maintaining 2 separate arrays is fragile. it would make more sense to create a struct that contains an income and a tax value, and populate the tax value with calls to your function (and perhaps a map statement that mutates your struct and applies tax values to each struct.)

Comment: Why is is explicitly typed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Duncan ! Found a small typo in your code: missing closing bracket for calculatePercentage.

Comment: Jessy, the compiler isn’t always able to figure out the type from closures. It doesn’t hurt anything to add an explicit type, and I didn’t have a compiler handy to see if it was needed in this case.